# Show that if $E\subseteq F$ is a subfield and $f,g\in E[x]$ then $\gcd(f,g)$ (relative to $F$) is in $E$

Tags: polynomials

> Show that if $E\subseteq F$ is a subfield and $f,g\in E[x]$ then $\gcd(f,g)$ (relative to $F$) is in $E$

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

It seems like if we look at the prime factorization of $f$ and $g$ over $E[x]$, we can find the $\gcd$ factorized to primes, while if we move to $F[x]$ and factorize, we should get that the $\gcd$ has the same degree, but I am unable to prove it..

Edit: Well, I tried thinking about Wojowu's hint, So if I write

$$f = q\cdot g +r$$ It is enough for me to show that $r\in E[x]$ to continue with Euclid's algorithm until I reach a gcd in $E[x]$. This would follow from proving that $q\cdot g\in E[x]$, but even that I have a problem proving..

Comment: Hint: Use [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: @Wojowu Tried to think about it, but not sure how to use it... I mean I can just theoretically talk about the reminder at the end, so I assume I need to show that the algorithm gives the same result no matter the field, but I'm not actually sure how to show it...